# How could I get my SVN-only host to pull from a git repository?

Tags: svn, git, build-automation, capistrano

I'd really like to get our host to pull from our Git repository instead of uploading files manually, but it doesn't have Git installed.

So is there a way to trick Subversion (which they do have) into checking out a Git repository?

I think I already know the answer, namely bug my host to add Git and live with it until they do, but I thought I would ask anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page should provide a workaround for your problem.

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit

Basically, you create a read-only clone of your Git repository in the SVN repository format, exporting updates as you go. An SVN hook could be written that fires after each update to copy the new files where you need them.